# How can I change the date formats in Perl?

Tags: perl

I just want to convert the dates from `20111230` format to `30-dec-2011`.

Answer (score 8):

In keeping with TMTOWTDI, you can use [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/Time-Piece-1.20/Piece.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime("20111230", "%Y%m%d");
print $t->strftime("%d-%b-%Y\n");
```

Comment: Time::Piece also comes with Perl, starting with v5.10.

Answer (score 5):

If I can't use one of the date modules, [POSIX](https://www.metacpan.org/module/POSIX) isn't so bad and it comes with `perl`:

```
use v5.10;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $date = '19700101';

my @times;
@times[5,4,3] = $date =~ m/\A(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\z/;
$times[5] -= 1900;
$times[4] -= 1;

# strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year, wday = -1, yday = -1, isdst = -1)
say strftime( '%d-%b-%Y', @times );
```

Making `@times` is a bit ugly. *You can't always get what you want, but if you try sometimes, you might find you get what you need.*

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use [Date::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3a%3aSimple):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Date::Simple qw(d8);

my $d = d8('20111230');
print $d->format('%d-%b-%Y'), "\n";

__END__

30-Dec-2011
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution.

```
my $date = '20111230';
my @months = (
    'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr',
    'May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep',
    'Oct','Nov','Dec'
);

if($date =~ m/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/){
        print $3 . '-' . $months[$2-1] . '-' . $1;
}
```

Comment: This one doesn't require packages that aren't in the base PERL install, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution. It uses [`DateTimeX::Easy`](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTimeX%3a%3aEasy):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTimeX::Easy;

my $dt = DateTimeX::Easy->parse('20111230');
print lc $dt->strftime('%d-%b-%G');
```