# Formatting dates with three-letter months in CSV file

Tags: regex, perl, csv

I have a CSV file where dates have the format `ddMMMyyyy` or `ddMMMyyyy:hh:mm:ss` (the month being English, three-letter, all-caps abbreviations and the other numbers having leading zeros). I have being doing some processing with regex in other files, but I don't know how to transform the month efficiently (without running through the file replacing 12 times). I need to transform everything to a more standard `yyyy-mm-dd` (all digits with leading zeros).

Comment: What is your question? What do you want the result to be?

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to specify I wanted a standard `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Comment: did you look into this thread?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675706/how-can-i-change-the-date-formats-in-perl

Comment: I was trying to go the other way (letter to number), but I'm not familiar with Perl so it's a little bit tricky to tweak the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the Time::Piece module that has been a standard part of Perl since 2007.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Time::Piece;

my $fmt = '%d%b%Y';
$_ = '00039222910,12Jul1999,283.23,290.33,13Jul2013:12:50:01,13Jul2013:12:50:01,AH';

s/(\d\d\w\w\w\d\d\d\d)/convert($1)/ge;

say $_;

sub convert {
  my $in = shift;
  my $d;

  eval { $d = Time::Piece->strptime($in, $fmt) };

  return $@ ? $in : $d->ymd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I run this from the terminal for every line of the file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you having? This isn't a "write my code for me" service. You need to make some effort yourself :-)

Comment: I got it to work but it's kind of ugly :) In the terminal I'm running `perl -pe 'BEGIN { use strict; use warnings; use 5.010; use Time::Piece; my $fmt = "%d%b%Y"; sub convert { my $in = shift; my $d; eval { $d = Time::Piece->strptime($in, $fmt) }; return $@ ? $in : $d->ymd; } } s/(\d\d\w\w\w\d\d\d\d)(:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})?/convert($1)/ge' sample.csv > final.csv`. How do I run this from a file? (Sorry for perl/terminal newbness!)

Comment: Just put your code in a file and put `while (<>) { ... }` around the bit that processes a line.