# Perl - Convert date from YEAR-MM-DD to MONTH, DD, YEAR

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, date

I am pulling a string from a database that is in the format `YEAR-MM-DD`, ie 2013-2-24 and need it to be printed on a webpage in the format of `Month, DD, YEAR` i.e. February, 24, 2013

I have to use perl to do this but am new to the language. 
So far I have figured that I need to convert the month number into a string with something like this:

```
 my @months = ("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
```

and pull data from the database with:

```
{Table}->get('date')
```

But I'm not sure how to put this all together, any help is appreciated.

I have gotten to this: but it doesn't seem to work.

```
use Date::Format;
@date = {Table}->get('date')
$date->time2str("%B %d %Y", @date);
print date;
```

Maybe it is failing because of the format it is in in the database? yyyy-mm-dd , would dashes cause it to fail? Do I need to convert it into just numbers first or something?

Comment: Just pull it from the database using `date_format()` to get it in your desired format.

Comment: "February, 24, 2013" isn't very grammatically correct...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675706/how-can-i-change-the-date-formats-in-perl

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $date = '2013-2-24';

print Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%Y-%m-%d')->strftime("%B %d, %Y"), "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
February 24, 2013
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the `DateTime::Format::MySQL` module from CPAN, your life will be much easier as it's custom-made to do exactly what you're doing.

```
use DateTime::Format::MySQL;
my $date_from_database_table =  '2013-2-24';
my $dt = DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_datetime($date_from_database_table);
print join(',',  $dt->month_name(), $dt->day, $dt->year) ."\n";
```

Since you're new to Perl, you should take a look at the [Task::Kensho](https://metacpan.org/pod/Task::Kensho) module list.  It will tell you the modules the Perl community recommends to tackle a certain problem.  You'll see that `Date::Format` has fallen out of favor in favor of the `DateTime` module, and in `DateTime` you'll see it doesn't parse dates itself but does have a whole host of modules to format dates under its `DateTime::Format` namespace.