# Date format conversion in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, date

Am new to Perl, I need a help to achieve below requirement with date format conversion.

Input date value --> 1/2/2015 (ie d/m/yyyy)

Output date value --> 2015-02-01  (ie yyyy-mm-dd)

What i tried so far is ,
First extract data , month and year values and do the proper formatting like pad zero(0) if date or month value is a single digit

```
$time = join '-', sprintf('%02d', substr ('1/2/2015'.'0'x2,0,4)) =~ /../g;
printf $time;
```

and concatenate these values with `-` to get the output. Is there any better approach to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your code that you have attempted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the date formats in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675706/how-can-i-change-the-date-formats-in-perl)

Comment: show what code you have tried, then people will be willing to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to use a module that's designed for date parsing and formatting, e.g., [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) or [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $str = '1/2/2015';
my $tp  = Time::Piece->strptime($str, '%m/%d/%Y');

say $tp->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
```

Output:

```
2015-01-02
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex. This will do the trick, but you need to ensure your input format will consistently be `d/m/yyyy`

```
my ( $d, $m, $y ) = split( '/', '1/2/2015' );
my $ymd = sprintf( '%d-%02d-%02d', $y, $m, $d );
print $ymd; # OUTPUT: 2015-02-01
```

If you want to do it in one line (and make your code less readable at the same time) you could do this.... though I generally would not recommend it.

```
print join( '-', reverse map { sprintf( '%02d', $_ ) } split( '/', '1/2/2015' ) );
```

You could compact this line by removing all rounded brackets `()` and most spaces, but that would further impact the readability of this expression.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer if it solved your problem.